# Download css and js in one file (package)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm working on optimising a site and one of the biggest issues it has is that there are far too many resource requests.

JavaScript and CSS bundling and minification go a long way to improve this but they're somewhat at odds with transparent naming.

For example, if I have 3 widgets on my page that all have their own JS and CSS, I could bundle all the JS into one file and all the css into another file. this would reduce the round-trips from 6 to 2. However, the resulting bundle would be wasteful if another page only used one of those 3 widgets.

What I'd like to do is bundle all the JS *AND* CSS for a particular widget into a single file. The browser would then have to unpack this and make it available to the page. A logical extension to this would be to create a package of packages so that all the resource files for all the widgets were downloaded in a single file.

The only way I can think of doing this is with a web service and then writing the output directly to the document with JavaScript. This feels wrong as I don't think the browser would be cache this appropriately.

Any thoughts?

---

**TL; DR**

Has anyone come up with a way of packaging CSS and JS files into a single file to reduce round-trips to the server?

Comment: In short: I don't think so. You could technically store the CSS as a JS variable and then create a `style` element and add the string as its `content`, which would technically pack both in one file, with the downside that if theres no JS, theres no CSS. The best, official, way to 'pack' it all in one file is to simply include them all as inline scripts and styles, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful for you but, when i create sites I load specific JS/CSS files by body classes with PHP if/else statements. Adding a body class of "slider" for example to load a sliders JS and CSS.

Comment: Use gulp or any build system. 

read this - https://martinwolf.org/2014/08/12/force-a-concatenation-order-with-gulp-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but one hack is to create a html file and add your js and css in it and import that file in your original html file

something like this

```
<head>
   <link rel="import" href="library.html">
</head>
```

and your library will look like this

```
<html><script>YOUR JS code</script><style>YOUR STYLES</style></html>
```

Comment: Would this `import` statement not do the same as simply using a `<script src="">` tag and also incur a request to the server anyhow? If the file is separate, the request is separate, no matter how you ask for it. It's also just a working draft and Firefox has no support, and Chrome needs a flag enabled, so for now this isn't a viable solution, if it solves the problem in the first place.

Comment: The link-import idea sounds like exactly what I'm after. It allows the browser to differentiate between the individual resources whilst still only taking a single round-trip to retrieve (if I understand it correctly).

The downside is that it's not well enough supported. I'm lucky in that we don't support older browsers but import isn't yet supported by FF IE or Safari.

Comment: What's the browser support?

Comment: I think it supports all browsers but not IE :)

Answer (score 3):

As [somethinghere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991619/somethinghere), it is not a good idea to package both in a single file and send it to the client. A CSS cannot add JavaScript, but a JavaScript can be used to include CSS to the body. So the only way is to add the CSS as a single string variable and making `document.createElement` and appending it to the `head`.

If you are concerned about the HTTP requests, you can either embed the CSS fully inside the `<head>` or you can make use of Data URI Scheme. The downside of Data URI Scheme is that, the browsers IE 8 and below have less or no support.

**Solution:** It is a **must** and best to include three requests at a minimum, for:

- The page itself
- CSS Stylesheet
- JavaScript Scripts

**Other Solutions** include adding the CSS and JavaScript contents directly inside the `<head>` or using the Data URI scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We use Data URI for some small inline things like icons. I don't think that the JS and CSS would work quite so well as they're just too large in general and I don't want the devs to have to re-encode them after each change.